# Награда от духа

Tags: поддержка, конкурс, дух-сообщества

Смотрю на [этот ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630505/178988) и вижу награду в 25 баллов, про которую говорится:

> За данный ответ было присуждено вознаграждение в размере 25 баллов репутации участником Дух сообщества

Как такое может быть?

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

А что вас смущает?

> Если в течение 7 дней (и «периода щедрости») ни один ответ не побеждает в конкурсе, половина суммы награды присуждается автору ответа, созданного после объявления о вознаграждении и получившего наибольший рейтинг (более 2 баллов). Если два или более ответа, подходящих под условия награды, имеют одинаковый рейтинг (т.е. в случае «ничьей» по баллам), награду получает первый по времени ответ. Если ни один ответ не подходит под условия награды, она не присуждается никому.

Если конкурс-стартер не выбирает никого, то за него половину награды распределяет Дух

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: Я про половину в курсе, но я считал, что в сообщении указывается участник, которому эта репутация принадлежала, а тут вдруг Дух. А оказывается, речь именно о том, кто назначил ответ получившим награду.